# Почему я получаю такую ошибку? PIL

Tags: python, pil, pillow

код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def makeanagliph(filename, delta):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    x, y = image.size
    pixels = image.load()
    new_image = image.copy()
    new_pixels = new_image.load()
    x1, y1 = new_image.size
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
            new_pixels[i + delta, j + delta] += r, g, b
    new_image.save("res.jpg", "JPG")
makeanagliph("image.png", 10)
```

ошибка:

```
cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: В какой строчке возникает ошибка? А ещё лучше - просто приведите весь текст ошибки полностью.

Comment: У вас случайно не чёрно-белое изображение?